# htaccess redirect directory to single page in same directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

All attempts failed... I want http://olex-design.at/journal to to be redirected to http://olex-design.at/journal/alle through .htaccess.

So far I have the following - non working - rule in place which produces a 403 forbidden page.

```
RewriteRule ^journal/$ /journal/alle [R=301,L]
```

The .htaccess file is placed in the root directory. Maybe someone can point me towards the right direction...

All rules in .htaccess files:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

#Force non-www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olex-design\.at [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://olex-design.at/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]

RewriteRule ^journal/$ /journal/alle [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Comment: Do you still get the 403 error if   the first line **Options -...** is removed/commented out ?

Comment: I think your **/journal/.htaccess** is overriding the request. You need to place the rule is that htaccess not root.

Comment: @starkeen Can you be more specific - I don't think I understand what exactly needs to be done.

Removing "Options..." doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Would it be possible that the base tag  <base href="http://olex-design.at/"> is the reason for the 301 redirection not working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the support of my webhost I was able to resolve my issues described above. This is the complete code in my .htaccess file.

Please note that the first 4 lines did the trick. The code below is responsible to remove the "www", remove the "index" when your in home (http://olex-design.at) and remove the .html file extension.

```
RewriteOptions inherit  
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^journal\/?$ "http\:\/\/olex\-design\.at\/journal\/alle" [R=301,L]

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olex-design\.at [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://olex-design.at/$1 [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#index redirect 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://olex-design.at/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```